# php using a composer package VMWarephp

Tags: php

I have a RHEL server that hosts a Laravel/php application.

The backend is a MySQL database.

There are console commands and controllers.

The Laravel code uses a vmwarephp package which I think uses composer.
composer appears to be installed.

My predecessor set it all up.

Unfortunately I don't have much Laravel knowledge or php knowledge.

I'm using php version 7.

I was hoping to connect to VMWare as a simple php program and not use Laravel.
Laravel is something else I'll learn later.

This is the package structure:
[image]

I was hoping to use the Vhost.php as follows in a php program:

```
enter code here
use '/var/www/html/vendor/vmwarephp/vmwarephp/library/Vmwarephp/Vhost.php';
....

$hostname='myvcenter';
$username='service';
$password='service password';
$vhost = new Vhost($hostname, $username, $password );

$virtualMachines = $vhost->findAllManagedObjects('VirtualMachine', array('configStatus'));

$vmdetails=[];
....
```

Unfortunately I get this error:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''/var/www/html/vendor/vmwareph'

Can some kind person please tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: The [`use` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/language.namespaces.importing.php) does not accept a string literal. I think you might actually want [`require_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.require-once.php) instead

Comment: Thanks...that was what I was looking for.